# Xcode 4 built-in help for your own files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, documentation, xcode4

Xcode 4 has a very nice built-in help/documentation that you can access e.g. by alt-clicking an identifier in the code, or by opening the help panel in the right sidebar. However, this only works for classes and methods provided by Apple. Is there a way to write some kind of documentation comments (e.g. like the Javadoc comments in Java) in your own code to make Xcode display them in those documentation panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like there's no good tool really... there are a few different ones, but they're imperfect and difficult to configure. I couldn't get Doxygen or Appledoc to work, and the tool mentioned by Avizzv92 is referred to as "a pile of poo" elsewhere, so I'd rather not try it... :)

Info that I've found:

[How do you document your source code in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174315/how-do-you-document-your-source-code-in-xcode)

http://wangling.me/2010/07/documentation-set-generation-tool-in-xcode-is-wanted/

http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html

http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp/

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Apr/msg00238.html

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html

It's maintained by Apple so it should be well supported. I never actually used it, may try it later.